# Spring 5.0.4 & Jackson2 throws excepiton on startup

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson2

I am trying to make simple REST service but faced with 2 problems.
1. Any method of REST controller returns 406 http error;

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getUser/{id}", headers = "Accept=application/json",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> getUser(@PathVariable(value = "id")Long id) {
    if (id == null) return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    UserInfo userInfo = userService.get(id);


    if (userInfo == null) return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userInfo, HttpStatus.OK);
}
@GetMapping(value = "/getUsers", headers = "Accept=application/json",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public List<UserInfo> getUsers()
{
    return userService.getAll();
}
```

So google told me, that problem can be in missing Jackson2 dependencies.
  But adding this dependencies cause this error, adding lower versions either results the same output or 406

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>


> 06-May-2018 15:36:45.477 WARNING [http-nio-25565-exec-3]
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh
> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in
> class path resource
> [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
> Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested
> exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you get the 406 code? Are you trying to access from browser?

Comment: this is probably caused by the accept header, you do not need that, since you are not sending anything in the body. You could also use `consumes` property

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn yes

Comment: @zakariaamine what media type should i consume then if i am trying to access though browser?

Comment: `consumes` refers to the content type of  what the method or the endpoint expects and not what you receive ( e.g the browser). What you receive is defined by `produces`

Comment: @zakariaamine yep, but without consumes its still 406, and with it is 416 "Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: in the code above you are not using `consumes`. You should remove `headers = "Accept=application/json"`

Comment: same result with 
    @GetMapping(value = "/getUsers", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public List<UserInfo> getUsers(){
        return userService.getAll();
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring 5 or above, **BeanInstantiationException** class is responsible for throwing **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException** as a nested exception.

As evident from the above exception the root cause of this exception is missing class **InvalidDefinitionException**. This class has been introduced in jackson databind API since 2.9.0 version onwards.

So to resolve this issue simply add jackson databind dependency with version 2.9.0 or above

**<dependency>

           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>

           <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>

           <version>2.9.0</version>

</dependency>**

Thanks !!

Comment: I wonder if there's any way to use 2.6.7 or 2.6.0 with Spring 5.x.y... 
I have some troubles do to some complicated response hierarchies which work well with 2.6.7 but not with any newer version. I must upgrade Spring to 5.x.y from 4.2.x but Spring also requires a newer version of jackson so it crashes.